# Special integrands in the calculus of variations

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Most techniques in the calculus of variations that I know of, deal with integrands of the form

$W(x, \phi(x), \nabla \phi(x)): \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ that give rise to functionals of the form

$$J(\phi) = \int_{\Omega} W(x, \phi(x), \nabla \phi(x)) \ dx, \ \phi \in W^{k,p}(\Omega) \text{ for some suitable } k, p$$

Currently, however, I'm interested in functionals where the integrand cannot be
expressed in the way above, because, for example, $\phi$ appears in a convolution $(\Psi \ast \phi)(x)$, $\Psi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, or some type of integral transform acts on $\phi$.

Focusing on the case where the integrand is of the form
$$ (\Psi \ast \phi)(x) + W(x, \phi(x), \nabla \phi(x))$$
for $\Psi \in L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\phi \in W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$  and $k,p, q$, $W:\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$ so that this expression is well defined.

My **question** is: Is there an easy way to carry results (like existence of minimizers) from the classical theory over to this case?

Comments are greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Alejandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Key idea in Direct method is *compactness*, i.e., the coercivity, and the *(weak) lower semi-continuous*.

If in your Lagrange, (we usually call the integrand in energy function as Lagrange), especially the term $(\Phi\ast \phi)(x)$ is bounded below and process lower semi-continuous, then by direct method you will have a minimizers. (I assume the term $W$ has all properties that Direct method need, i.e., the coercivity and convexity)

Comment: Thanks for your answer wisher!